# Adding an element to a collection type without changing the collection type in Python

Tags: python

Lets say I have a class that would work having either a tuple, a list, a dictionary, or a set of another type of object.

Something like this:

```
class AbstractClass:
    """An example class"""

    def __init__(self, items=None):
        self.items = items

    def items(self):
        """Returns the items that this instance has"""
        return self.items
```

Now I want to add a method like this:

```
def add_item(self, item):
    """Adds item to items"""
    # code goes here
```

Now I'm stuck. I don't want to have to check if items is a list, tuple, and etc. and then do it on a case by case basis (as it simply seems unpythonic), but there doesn't seem to be one method that works universally. I would also want to try and preserve the type, so I don't want to convert items to a list (for example) and then use list's method of adding an item (either with `items.append(item)` or `items + [item,]`). Any suggestions?

The following is a limited list of examples for the expected behavior:

**List**

```
a = AbstractClass([1, 2])
a.add_item(4) # a.items now contains [1, 2, 4] in any order
```

**Tuple**

```
a = AbstractClass((1, 2))
a.add_item(4) # a.items now contains (1, 2, 4) in any order
```

**Dictionary** (note: this one is really quite optional, as I don't expect to be using this)

```
a = AbstractClass({0:1, 2:2})
a.add_item({3:4}) # a.items now should be {0:1, 2:2, 3:4}
```

### Note: This is not meant to be used in practice, I just wanted to test the limits of python's dynamic nature

Comment: What sort of behavior are you looking for?  You can't add a new element to a tuple at all.  Adding something to a dict would mean adding both a key and a value, whereas adding something to a list would be just appending a value.  The way you "add an item" to each kind of structure is different on the conceptual level, so it's not clear what your generic `add_item` is supposed to do.

Comment: There is no universal way to add items, dicts,tuples, and lists etc.. are very different structures

Comment: What would it mean to add an item to a dict?  Would it be the key or the value?  Or are your items always 2-tuples?

Comment: By adding an element to a tuple, I would probably mean that my tuple becomes a tuple that contains the original elements and the new one. As for dicts, I would like it to just add it to an unused key, if it all possible to do something like that.

Comment: It would probably help if you could give examples of what you want the result to be when `items` is a list, dict, etc.

Comment: without some check it is impossible to do what you are trying to do

Comment: "As for dicts, I would like it to just add it to an unused key, if it all possible to do something like that." - you mean like generate a random number for the key?  What could be the use case for such a monstrosity?  You'd be better off with a list then, it seems.

Comment: I'm trying to stretch python's dynamic nature to it's limits.

Comment: That dictionary implementation is completely pointless, and I won't change my answer for it because it makes no sense.

Comment: probably for dict, it should be: a.add_item({3:4})?

Comment: Why in all honesty would you be adding keys to a dict with no values that mean anything, you have one method to add the items so you can never add anything else later in your code without checking the type which you say you don't want to do, accept the fact that you just cannot do what you are trying to do.

Comment: Padraic is right, this is completely unfeasible (without going by a case-by-case basis) if you have to accommodate dictionaries.

Comment: @rth that is actually a good idea, would that help with a generic version?

Comment: @ThomasHobohm the basic idea of that dict was that the value would be added irregardless of the "structure" of `items`

Comment: Yes, but the key / value would essentially have no meaning.

Comment: Well the key/value relationship would be killed, but the value would still be added, which is more important in my case. But actually that can be fixed by adding an optional parameter specifying a function that would map the item to a key, but that seems too specific of a use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this and it will work for all of the standard collection types:

```
def add_item(self, item):
    # You could use append here, and it'd be faster
    temporary_list = list(self.items) + [item]
    self.items = type(self.items)(temporary_list)
```

This works because `type(x)` returns the "type" of that object. To extract out the actual type string ("list", "set", "tuple", etc.), we have to do some string manipulation. We can then construct a statement equivalent to:

```
# For lists
self.items = list(temporary_list)
# For sets
self.items = set(temporary_list)
# And so on...
```

EDIT: I have no idea why I was downvoted. Stackoverflow advises against downvoting without explaining why, just so you know.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I would guess that whoever did may have done so because your solution is probably pretty slow and more importantly, nobody likes exec/eval when it isn't truly necessary (which it almost never is).

Comment: I understand, but it works, and it's the only real way to do it without going on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Did you actually try this?  It won't work.  Even if you could do this, there would be no need to use `exec` to do it.  You can just call `type(self.items)` directly.  But it won't work anyway for several reasons.  For instance, calling `list` on a dict only returns a list of the keys, so all the value information will be thrown away.

Comment: I did actually try this. You can't call type(self.items) directly! Why don't you try it. Anyway, there would be absolutely no way to do this with dictionaries, so this is a solution which works for lists, sets, and tuples. For dictionaries, you'd have to have arguments for the key and value, there'd be a bunch of problems with those arguments, and it just wouldn't work, so I didn't include them in my answer. If the OP clarified how his theoretical object would work with dictionaries, then I would edit my answer to accommodate the changes.

Comment: Yes you can.  Your exec line could be replaced by `self.items = type(self.items)(temporary_list)`.  This will indeed work for tuples, lists, and sets, but saying it works for all container types when the question specifically mentions dicts is misleading.  I agree the question is ill-posed, but that just means there may be no right answers.

Comment: Hmm, that syntax does work. I wish you'd been a little bit more clear about it, though. I tried doing that (with very slightly modified syntax), and it didn't work. I've edited my answer, however.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for method names you think will work, if you don't want to use isinstance():

```
def __init__(self, items=None):
    self.items = items
    if hasattr(self.items, 'add'):
        self.add_item = self.items.add
    elif hasattr(self.items, 'append'):
        self.add_item = self.items.append
    else:
        raise Exception("no add method found")
```

Comment: This is basically going on a case-by-case basis, which is exactly what the question poster said he didn't want.

Comment: This is a bit more generic, and doesn't quite depend on changes to python's types over time, so it is indeed better than a simple case by case. However, it doesn't handle tuples (which are immutable, and so would need a separate case).

Comment: The OP didn't want to go case-by-case on types, but if you go by methods there are far fewer possible choices.